# Attempting set custom arrayAdapter and getting nullpointer exception with listView.setAdapter method, despite apparent pathway

Tags: android, listview

I know these exceptions happen when the code has nothing to grab for the method, but I am not sure why my intended pathway isn't working. I have a custom adapter (MusicAdapter) grabbing a list of items, setting it to a listView.xml file, and setting the screen with setAdapter().

When trying this, I get the error message
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference.

The MyMusicActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.android.musicapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyMusicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<Music> music = new ArrayList<Music>();

    //nonsense examples
    music.add(new Music("The Who", "Won't Get Fooled Again", "Who's Next"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));
    music.add(new Music("mother?", "әṭa","as"));

    MusicAdapter adapter = new MusicAdapter(this, music);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.music_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The music_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/music_list"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The MusicAdapter file:

```
package com.example.android.musicapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MusicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Music> {
public MusicAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Music> words) {
    // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
    // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
    // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
    // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
    super(context, 0, words);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.music_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link Music} object located at this position in the list
    Music currentMusic = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the music_item.xml layout with the artist text
    TextView artistTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_text_view);
    // Get the artist from the current music object and
    // set this text on the number TextView
    artistTextView.setText(currentMusic.getArtist());

    // Find the TextView in the music_item.xml layout with the title text
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
    // Get the title from the current music object and
    // set this text on the name TextView
    titleTextView.setText(currentMusic.getTitle());

    // Find the TextView in the music_item.xml layout with the album text
    TextView albumTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.album_text_view);
    // Get the album from the current music object and
    // set this text on the name TextView
    albumTextView.setText(currentMusic.getAlbum());

    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 3 TextViews)
    // so that it can be shown in the ListView
    return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you inflating the ListView into? I don't see a call to setContentView(R.layout.some_root_layout); in the Activity's onCreate().

Comment: This was the problem, thank you! It works great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't setting the `contentView` for the activity. The error is saying that the `listView` is not found. At the top of your `onCreate` make sure you call `setContentView(R.layout.[YOUR_LAYOUT_XML])`.